# Crontab suddenly changes mail address

Tags: email, cron, notifications

For years I have been using an rsync_script to do daily backups.  Each morning I have received an email as root to confirm.

After a recent update, it started sending emails to my user account;
I have MAILTO=root in the crontab config.

I have searched for the above problem but everything I find seems to be asking how to disable this - my problem is the reverse!

Any ideas?
cheers,
Nigel

Manually adding MAILTO=root to config file, even thought it was not there before and I got emails as root.
Expecting it to carry on sending emails to root!